# Why do I have this "undefined method form" with my RoR app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, partial

I have a partial

```
= form.fields_for :cycles do |c|
  %tr{:style=>"border-right:none;"}
%td{:width=>"16%"}
  = c.text_field :day, :size=>6
  = c.hidden_field :id
%td{:width=>"35%"}= c.text_field :hour, :size=>15
%td{:width=>"35%"}= c.text_field :hour_night, :size=>15
%td{:style => "width:7%;padding:0;border-right:none",:align=>"center"}
  = c.hidden_field :_destroy
  = link_to image_tag("panel_tools/delete.png",:size=>"15x15"), nil, :href =>"", :onclick => "check_nested_attr_destroy(this);return false;"
```

I call this from the view like this

```
= form_for(@schedule_of_working, @new_action ? {:url => schedule_of_workings_path} : {:url => schedule_of_working_path, :method=> :put}) do |f| 
.....
= render(:partial=>'cycles', :collection => @schedule_of_working.cycles, :locals => {:form => f}) if @schedule_of_working.cycles.count > 0
```

I'm getting an error about undefined method form..

rails -v 3.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rails only really works well when you follow its conventions.**

You should avoid using:  hidden fields, `put` with a form, passing in the action that way and I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the url in various parts, but anyway avoid these unless you have really good reason why you are not structuring it according to convention.  Focus more on your routes and how resources are setup and your models and their relationships and your views should be very minimalist.  In them I'm not sure what the hour and hour_night are, or theor length 15.  Confusion mix of stuff.

So your form, as is, has a few problems.  Rather than specific advice I would just say re-write it.  It should be much simpler than this.  I would recommend watching some [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) on forms, e.g.
Forms Part [one](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1), [two](http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2) or [three](http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3)

Comment: Thanks fo replay, Michael!! In short i have model with 2 nested_attributes and i want them work in single form. Save there in single transaction. I used hidden field, because params hash of exists records come to controller like this. :nested_attr => {:id=>1{:atr1=>1..and so on}} and exists records appends not update. About form with varios urls, i want use this twice in a new action and edit action of controller.

Comment: params hash of exists records come to controller like this. :nested_attr => {"1"=>{:atr1=>1..and so}} on}}

Comment: and my cycle partial looks like this 
= form.fields_for :cycles do |c|
  %tr{:style=>"border-right:none;"}
    %td{:width=>"16%"}
      = c.text_field :day, :size=>6
      = c.hidden_field :id
    %td{:width=>"35%"}= c.text_field :hour, :size=>15
    %td{:width=>"35%"}= c.text_field :hour_night, :size=>15
    %td{:style => "width:7%;padding:0;border-right:none",:align=>"center"}
      = c.hidden_field :_destroy
      = link_to image_tag("panel_tools/delete.png",:size=>"15x15"), nil, :href =>"", :onclick => "check_nested_attr_destroy(this);return false;"

Comment: I would check my view again, may be found a way resolve my problem